# Can I repair Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with Live-CD?

Tags: boot-repair

Can I totally re-install or repair Ubuntu 14.04 with or without Live-CD?
I deleted the latest kernel by accident.
I will need step by step commands.

Comment: Have you kept any old kernels? Is your system still running? If so do not reboot.

Answer (score 0):

First make a bootable iso of your current drive in case something goes wrong. You can do this with http://clonezilla.org/. You can find the newest kernel at http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-16/.